# NVL in BETWEEN date AND

Tags: oracle, date, between

Ok have a lot of records and mayebe one order number = 11233.

part of code which is not correct

```
 AND a.C_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE (
                                   NVL ('&C_DATE_FROM', '1900-01-01'),
                                   'yyyy-mm-dd')
                            AND TO_DATE (
                                   NVL ('&C_DATE_TO', '2099-12-31'),
                                   'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

My question How Can I write a condition if a.C_DATE is null ???
Now I dont have a record when a.C_DATe is null

I wrote sth like this

```
 AND (a.C_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE (
                                   NVL ('&C_DATE_FROM', '1900-01-01'),
                                   'yyyy-mm-dd')
                            AND TO_DATE (
                                   NVL ('&C_DATE_TO', '2099-12-31'),
                                   'yyyy-mm-dd') OR a.C_DATE IS NULL)
```

but I'm waiting for a long time....

Comment: first: it seems to be a very long time span, second: is the C_DATE column indexed or at least part of an index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
AND (NVL(a.C_DATE, TO_DATE('1900-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')) 
     BETWEEN TO_DATE (NVL('&C_DATE_FROM', '1900-01-01'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')
         AND TO_DATE (NVL('&C_DATE_TO',   '2099-12-31'), 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

Comment: Its the best solution. Difrrent before solution with use C_DATE IS NULL and your solution (Mt. Schneiders) is about 3-4 minutes ;)

Thank U so much

Comment: [Err] ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Answer (score 1):

maybe this way?

```
AND ( 
   a.C_DATE BETWEEN 
       TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND TO_DATE ('2099-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
   OR a.C_DATE IS NULL
    )
```

why this larage date range?

Comment: only one month 6747 records :)

Comment: then it should be this way: AND (a.C_DATE IS NULL or a.C_DATE between ... your desired month ...     and you sould have indexed the column

Comment: Yes U also have a good idea but earlier solution (Mr. Schneiders) is OK for me and query quickly returns the result but Thank U for help :)